# Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, implementation, decompiling

Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?

Whenever I go to the decompiled implementation, I see only interfaces of methods, but not the implementation. I heard that some people claim that VS Code can show decompiled implementation as well and was wondering if it is true and how could I enable the feature in VS Code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suppose you have installed the `omnisharp` extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

You can turn on the setting "Enable Decompilation Support", which is disabled per default. After turning that on, you should be able to see the decompiled code right away.

[image]

You can read more about it here: https://www.strathweb.com/2020/05/decompilation-support-in-omnisharp-and-c-extension-for-vs-code/

Comment: I enabled it but I think I clicked `no` to the license agreement. Do you know how to reset the license agreement setting?

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing the extension again. Other than that, I don't know where to reset the license agreement.

Comment: thank you for the idea. It didn't work for me, but I did find this: `Setting "omnisharp.enableDecompilationSupport": true would also trigger a disclaimer warning which you need to accept, perhaps you didn't?

You can re-trigger the pop up by launching the CSharp: Show the decompiler terms agreement command`

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4817#issuecomment-941950241

Comment: Whenever I go into a decompiler function, most of the time it is either throwing null or empty. Compared to this, the Rider IDE's decompiler is far better. I am wondering whether I am doing something wrong?