# How to go to implementation of C# code in VSCode?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Prerequisites:

- I use Visual Studio Code `Version: 1.63.2 (Universal)`
- MacOS Monterey 12.03 with M1
- .NET version `6.0.302`

Originally I am coming from Python, but lately, I interact with C#(in particular ASP.NET Core 6) a lot.

I have been trying to find an answer to a question:

**How can I go to the implementation of the method/class in a dependency package installed in my .NET project? Is it possible to do it in VSCode?**

Probably, I am just struggling with how should I formulate this question, so let me provide some examples below.

If I am using PyCharm and, let's say, have an installed package `flask-login`. I can import the function `login_user` as on the screenshot below.

[image]

Then just go to its implementation and see the whole code as on the screenshot below.
[image]

This happens because both in PyCharm and in VSCode it redirects me to the files stored in the `bin` directory of my interpreter path. As a result, I can always go locally and check the source code of all installed dependencies.

Now coming back to C#: I want to have the same thing in my .NET project with VSCode (I don't use Visual Studio and use MacOS). As for now in VSCode, I can only go to the interface code of a dependency and when I press `go to implementation` it says `Implementation not found`.

I am not sure whether this is possible or not, since C# is a compiled language, so probably it would require a decompiler for this to work. The only thing I managed to make work was the possibility to jump into implementation during debugging session https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Debugging-into-the-.NET-Framework-itself. At the same time, this is slightly different from what I want -> I just want a convenient way to go into the implementation source code to understand what is happening in the code LOCALLY and probably set breakpoints in this code if I think it makes sense.

Therefore, my main question stays the same: **Can I do it on MacOS in VSCode?**

UPD: I tried Rider from JetBrains(https://www.jetbrains.com/rider) and it works there. Still interested in making this work in VSCode.

Comment: Use JetBrains Rider. I love VSCode and use it every day, but after all, I was forced to use Rider for navigating to implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer is basically here -> [Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893900/is-there-a-way-to-see-decompiled-c-sharp-code-in-vs-code)

There is a feature to enable decompilation in `omnisharp` extension for C# in VSCode.

Thanks to @UnholySheep!

Comment: Not working on .net 8 and VSCode