# Is there a way to see decompiled C# system libraries in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, implementation, decompiling

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70893900), I can view Unity's classes:

[image]

Notice it says "Decompiled with ...". With classes which are part of system libraries, it doesnt do that:

[image]

Notice the lack of "Decompiled with ..." string. Indeed, it looks like just the headers.

Is there some extra setting to turn on somewhere to decompile ALL code, including system libraries?

Comment: Several tools allow you to peek inside of .NET binaries. DotPeek standalone tool, and ReSharper plugin for VS will do it ad-hoc when inspecting code. Both of these tools are provided by Jetbrains. No need to decompile ALL code. If you just want to read you can browse Microsoft's github pages: https://github.com/dotnet

Comment: @AnthonyG. Thanks, but I was hoping for a built-in tool in VS Code. Having to use a standalone tool is a bit annoying, given I can just press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the source of Unity's libraries but not with C# system libraries, while that ReSharper plugin you mentioned is already included in the VS Code C# extension. As for the GitHub page, it seems to be only for modern versions (.NET > 6) - Unity still uses .NET Framework 4.x.