# VS Code and Godot .NET not stepping into GD.cs for example program

Tags: c#, installation, game-development, godot4

I am a beginner with Godot and I'm trying to get the debugger setup correctly.

I made a simple print script that outputs a print into the log.

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class CharacterController : Node2D
{
    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        Godot.GD.Print("Hello GD GoDot"); 
    }
}
```

Whenever I 'step in' its not finding GD.cs. Here is the output I am getting when stepping into the line,

```
[Error - 1:25:13 PM] [LanguageServerHost] System.UriFormatException: Failed create URI from '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'; original string: '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'
 ---> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.ProtocolConversions.CreateAbsoluteUri(String absolutePath) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Protocol/Extensions/ProtocolConversions.cs:line 180
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.ProtocolConversions.CreateAbsoluteUri(String absolutePath) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Protocol/Extensions/ProtocolConversions.cs:line 188
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.Handler.Diagnostics.DocumentPullDiagnosticHandler.GetDiagnosticSources(DiagnosticKind diagnosticKind, Boolean nonLocalDocumentDiagnostics, Boolean taskList, RequestContext context, IGlobalOptionService globalOptions) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Protocol/Handler/Diagnostics/DocumentPullDiagnosticHandler.cs:line 119
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.Handler.Diagnostics.Public.PublicDocumentPullDiagnosticsHandler.GetOrderedDiagnosticSourcesAsync(DocumentDiagnosticParams diagnosticParams, RequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Protocol/Handler/Diagnostics/Public/PublicDocumentPullDiagnosticsHandler.cs:line 97
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer.Handler.Diagnostics.AbstractPullDiagnosticHandler`3.HandleRequestAsync(TDiagnosticsParams diagnosticsParams, RequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Features/LanguageServer/Protocol/Handler/Diagnostics/AbstractPullDiagnosticHandler.cs:line 165
   at Microsoft.CommonLanguageServerProtocol.Framework.QueueItem`3.StartRequestAsync(TRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[Error - 1:25:13 PM] Request textDocument/diagnostic failed.
  Message: Failed create URI from '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'; original string: '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'
  Code: -32000 
[object Object]
[Error - 1:25:13 PM] Document pull failed for text document file:///root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs
  Message: Failed create URI from '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'; original string: '/root/godot/modules/mono/glue/GodotSharp/GodotSharp/Core/GD.cs'
  Code: -32000 
[object Object]
```

Its showing an empty file on the screen, but then the print completes - not sure why the print can run but the debugger cant find the file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roFrL.png)

Here is my lanuch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch + Debug",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "D:/Godot_v4.2.1-stable_mono_win64/Godot_v4.2.1-stable_mono_win64.exe",
            "console": "internalConsole", 
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "requireExactSource": false,
            "enableStepFiltering": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

The top error refers to the URI, is there a place this can be configured? Any ideas how to resolve?

Tried many tutorials on launch.json and task.json, the debugger attaches just cant step into the Godot .cs files.

Comment: What OS?  The pathnames  have forward slashes which probably means Linux and not Windows which uses backslashes.

Comment: Windows. '/' are said to be used when defining the program path - "program": "D:/Godot_v4.2.1-stable_mono_win64/Godot_v4.2.1-stable_mono_win64.exe"

There are no issues finding the engine .exe just cant step into GD.cs or any of the godot files.

Comment: The debug file is a pdb extension.  It should be in same folder as the executable.  See if it exists.  You may of only build the release version and not the debug version or you project is linked to the release folder.  Open the main csproj file with a text editor and see if you are link to the debug or release folder.

Comment: Here is the .csproj file opened in Notepad -

<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/4.2.1">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFramework Condition=" '$(GodotTargetPlatform)' == 'android' ">net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFramework Condition=" '$(GodotTargetPlatform)' == 'ios' ">net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: cant see a file with a .pdb extension in the folder

Comment: It is only in the bin\debug folder, not the release.  Check other projects to see if you are getting pdb in other projects.

Comment: Did you build the debug version or only the release version?

Comment: I presume you need a debug build of Godot for this. You can get one by [Building from source](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/compiling/index.html). As alternative, see also: [Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893900/is-there-a-way-to-see-decompiled-c-sharp-code-in-vs-code).