# Any Way to View c# Source Code in VsCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to view the source code from the standard library (meaning all namespaces from c#) in vscode? This is possible in visual studio but when I click on "Go To Definition" in vscode it will only give the signatures of the class/method that I want to view and not the actual implementation of it:
[image: Definition]

Additionally, it will tell me "No implementation found for "List" when I click "Go to Implementation":
[image]

UPDATE:

I tried using the suggestions in the following post: [Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893900/is-there-a-way-to-see-decompiled-c-sharp-code-in-vs-code) but still did not work. I have the "Enable Decompilation Support" setting checked:
[image]
and it will still give me a "no Implementation Found For List Error".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893900/is-there-a-way-to-see-decompiled-c-sharp-code-in-vs-code)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface I would still like to be able to click on the implementation like in visual studio and want to see if that is at all possible.

Comment: @Narish I tried what they said in that post and still didn't work. My question has been updated.

Comment: You can use SourceLink to debug into the library code. Check out this [blog post by Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/) to see how that also works for VS Code. That's working for me. Unfortunately this only allows you to see and step through the source code when debugging. At least in my current setup that's the case. Debugging works perfectly fine though. Not sure what would be required to also make it work with `Go to implemenation`. I'd be intrested in that as well.